# Error after pulling from a collegue (System.Runtime.DurableInstancing.InstancePersistenceCommandException)

Tags: c#, sql-server, workflow, workflow-foundation

i am trying to integrate a WF application of a collegue that i just pulled with Git. I've set up the database 'WF45GettingStartedTutorial' like in the msdn tutorial described.
When i try to start the host, i get the following error message:

> '{"The SqlWorkflowInstanceStore has a database version of '4.0.0.0'.
>   InstancePersistenceCommand
>   'System.Activities.DurableInstancing.CreateWorkflowOwnerWithIdentityCommand'
>   cannot be run against this database version.  Please upgrade the
>   database to '4.5.0.0'."}'

Of course i already googled that and tried the following from msdn:

Running the 'SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchemaUpgrade.sql' in'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en'. I executed that sql file from within the database 'WF45GettingStartedTutorial' in mssql 2012. My collegue was using mssql 2008 R2, don't know if that makes any difference here, but i get the message that the sql command completed successfully.

Although I've run the update script, i get the same error in the CommunicationHost again. (I've refreshed / updated the .edmx file)
The line, where my host crashes:

```
WorkflowApplication.CreateDefaultInstanceOwner(store, null,   WorkflowIdentityFilter.Any);
```

Does anybody know how to solve that issue ?
And why is it working on his computer but not on mine ?

Answer (score 0):

A newly created database isn't suitable as a WorkflowInstance Store; you need to create it, populate the schema and then upgrade it.

1. You need to create the database

   CREATE DATABASE [WF45GettingStartedTutorial]
2. open SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchema.sql and run it against your database (USE WF45GettingStartedTutorial)
3. open and run SqlWorkflowInstanceStoreSchemaUpgrade.sql

The SQL files will be in your Windows .NET directory, e.g.

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SQL\en\
```